# How to find all non-binary text files (with extended attributes) in a directory on OSX bash?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, find

The following command cann't work when the file name contains extended attributes.

```
cd ~/Library/Containers
find . -type f -name "*.xml"
```

It returned nothing. But

```
less com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music\ Library.xmlary.xml
```

The xml file is there.

Comment: Is any part of that path a symlink or other non-directory entity?

Comment: `com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Music` is a symlink; you need to use the `-L` option to recurse through the linked directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to follow the symbolic links in the directory hierarchy, you need to use the `-L` option to `find`:

```
find -L . -type f -name "*.xml"
```